# C++ initializer_list parameters - can they have default values?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The following code causes a C1001 internal error in Visual Studio 2013 (v12.0.30501.00 Update 2) - should I expect it to work?  (downloadable [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50191060/initializer_list_default_parameter.zip))

I was expecting to be able to call the `func` function without a `vals` argument and have the default of `{10.0}` used.

Any help appreciated!

C.hpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>
#pragma once

class C {
public:
    void func(std::string str, std::initializer_list<double> vals = { 10.0 });
};
```

C.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "C.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void C::func(std::string str, std::initializer_list<double> vals){
    cout << "str is " << str << endl;
    for (double v : vals){
        cout << v << endl;
    }
}
```

initializer_list_default_parameter.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "C.hpp"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    C inst;
    inst.func("name"); // this line causes a C1001 error with MSVC 2013
    //inst.func("name", { 4.3 }); this line compiles
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The fact that you get an *internal* error from VC++ should tell you that there's a bug in the compiler. Having `std::initializer_list` with default argument is okay.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the x86 compiler. Consider filing a bug report with Microsoft at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/. I can compile and run the code with no errors (Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.30501 for x64)

Comment: Ok thanks, I can work around this by just having two different `func` functions.  Have submitted a [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/details/925540)!

Comment: Given that you now know that `initializer_list` can be used with a default argument, and that you've found the bug (in x86 vs. not in the x64), consider typing it up as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, initializer_list parameters can have default values, but there's a bug in the MSVC 2013 x86 compiler meaning they're not supported (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/details/925540).